# Add new element to the right till the end of screen in Android

Tags: android, image, layout

Basically I have a lot of square pictures. I want to add them from left to right till the end of the screen, go to the next line and so on.

I'm looking for the best way to add as many element as possible in one line of a layout before going to the next line.

I'm currently using TableLayout with a fixed number of element per row which is not really convenient.

Is there a way to do it dynamically to be sure to cover every screen size and screen flip ?

Comment: Use gridview, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: Doesn't GridView are fixed in number of column and line ? I might have missed something if not.

Comment: If you are android developer then better to use component given by google rather then creating unnecessary burden of code while loading activity. Because if you dynamically load views, it will worked definitely but then you need to manage all the possibility of screen and screen rotation.

Comment: android:numColumns="auto_fit" of the GridView is perfect for me. Thank you for your help.